# Looking for cheat sheet to J.C. Reynolds symbols

Tags: terminology, reference-request, type-theory, abstract-data-types

Most specifically, his use of small epsilon introduced at the end of section 1 of "Types, Abstraction and Parametric Polymorphism" is throwing me, but in general I would like references to symbols in the Type and Logical Relations literature.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You aren't going to find a list of all notations ever used. Apart from a few standard notations, each paper will define the notation that it uses.

This paper is from the dark ages of typewriter typesetting, so the typographic quality is subpar. The character `ε` stands for $\in$, which is the standard mathematical notation for set membership.